# Why does Veronica attack me?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I don't know why but Veronica attacks me!

I'm not wearing faction armor my companion is Cass and I am idolized by Brotherhood.

Can it be fixed on Xbox? Or should I use previous save?

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the [Wikia page for Veronica](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Veronica_Santangelo) none of the actions you've taken should make her hostile. Since you are idolized by the brotherhood I'm assuming you haven't destroyed their bunker - the only action that would make her outright hostile. Anything else would just make her quit as a companion.

In the bugs section of her Wikia page there is nothing listed that would cause her to attack you. It is possible you have encountered a bug that isn't present on the Wikia page. If possible, reload a save from before she attacked you and either resume playing from there or replay your actions to troubleshoot what caused her to attack.

<strike>Lastly, can you verify if you have any mods installed? Mods may cause the game to behave in unintended ways and a bugged mod could be the reason she's hostile to your character.</strike>
You are playing on Xbox, it is unlikely you have mods installed

Answer (score -2):

its a reputation glitch you would have two options

1. kill Veronica
2. reload a point before then and try to avoid the glitch

Comment: Hello Apex, and welcome to Arqade! Could you link a source, and a quote from said source, into your answer? Answers usually need to have evidence of bugs, rather than just a claim. Also, when you edit your post, you should also include punctuation, and capitalize the correct letters. Your answer is difficult to read at this point.